# How to insert new table with JSON data through API in Azure SQL Database

Tags: json, api, azure-sql-database

I have the following problem. We are using **Azure SQL Database** for the Data processing. Instead of wizard import every time we would like to automatically **load the data through API** from our accounting platforms. (API Documentation Links: https://hellocashapi.docs.apiary.io/#introduction/authentication , https://www.zoho.com/books/api/v3/)

Basically my task is to get the data through API from these platforms and create the table in our Azure SQL Database and insert this data therein.

Can anyone recommend me the platform to resolve this issue? or please send me the link with the documentation which would show me the way to do that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, not all the API is supported as Source data in Data Factory.

Please reference this document: [Azure Data Factory connector overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-overview)

Data Factory doesn't support hellocashAPI. That means do that with Data Factory.

Secondly, Data Factory now support supports creating a destination table automatically. 
Referecec:[Copy Activity in Azure Data Factory supports creating a destination table automatically](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/copy-activity-in-azure-data-factory-supports-creating-destination-table-automatically/).

Summary:

Load data faster with new support from the Copy Activity feature of Azure Data Factory. Now, if you’re trying to copy data from an any supported source into SQL database/data warehouse and find that the destination table doesn’t exist, Copy Activity will create it automatically. After the data ingestion, review and adjust the sink table schema as needed.

This feature is supported with:

- Azure SQL Database
- Azure SQL Database Managed Instance
- Azure SQL Data Warehouse
- SQL Server

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you can put the JSON on a SQL variable like this

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'[  
  {  
    "Order": {  
      "Number":"SO43659",  
      "Date":"2011-05-31T00:00:00"  
    },  
    "AccountNumber":"AW29825",  
    "Item": {  
      "Price":2024.9940,  
      "Quantity":1  
    }  
  },  
  {  
    "Order": {  
      "Number":"SO43661",  
      "Date":"2011-06-01T00:00:00"  
    },  
    "AccountNumber":"AW73565",  
    "Item": {  
      "Price":2024.9940,  
      "Quantity":3  
    }  
  }
]
```

Then you can create a table using the WITH clause

```
SELECT * INTO TableName1
FROM OPENJSON ( @json )  
WITH (   
              Number   varchar(200)   '$.Order.Number',  
              Date     datetime       '$.Order.Date',  
              Customer varchar(200)   '$.AccountNumber',  
              Quantity int            '$.Item.Quantity',  
              [Order]  nvarchar(MAX)  AS JSON  
 )
```